encrypt-rsa encryptStringWithRsaPublicKey is this mean params rename?
I'm trying to refactor & upgrade my legacy project then i found this
From this changelog
const encryptedText = nodeRSA.encryptStringWithRsaPublicKey({ 
  text: 'hello', 
  - keyPath: path.join(__dirname, './public-key') 
  + publicKey: public 
});

is this mean i have to change parameter name ?
